# Checking external bitcoin address balances via JSON-RPC API

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, api, python

I'm using bitcoin core json-rpc api in python and am wondering why...

```
getreceivedbyaddress()
```

...doesn't allow me to specify an address that isn't in my local wallet?

The whole blockchain is open, I can search anyone's address/balance via a web browser, so why would the API prevent me checking?

Is there another method for doing this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin Core does not track each individual address, only the addresses associated with your wallet.

There are other clients, such as bitcore-insight and [btcd](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd), which maintain a separate address index.

Alternatively, you can implement an index yourself, or run an existing one such as [ElectrumX](https://github.com/kyuupichan/electrumx).